# Can broadcast from android but not from C#

Tags: c#, android, udp, ip, broadcast

I've got an app on my android, where if I turn on wifi and connect to my home wireless router, it is able to broadcast via UDP `DatagramSocket` ala `mSck.send(new DatagramPacket(lBuf, 5, InetAddress.getByName("255.255.255.255"), 13000))`, and I can see it on my desktop in wireshark.

However if I take my laptop and broadcast to `new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("255.255.255.255"), 13000)` via a C# `UdpClient` (connected over wifi to the same router), nothing shows up.

If I change that `UdpClient`'s broadcast address to `IPAddress.Parse("192.168.2.255")`, it works fine.  I've tried changing `UdpClient.EnableBroadcast` and every other property with no luck.  Any idea what could be going on here?

Comment: Firewall on the laptop blocking UDP broadcasts to `255.255.255.255`?

Comment: No, turned off windows firewall.